# Неправильное отображение заголовка Toolbar

Tags: android, android-sdk

Добавил Toolbar в приложение с помощью этого туториала: http://java-help.ru/?s=toolbar&submit=Search

Проблема в том, что у заголовка фон текста непрозрачный. Когда я использовал стандартный Toolbar такого не было. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробежался по туториалу, ничего такого нет там, чтобы вызывало такой резонанс.

Comment: вы небось в стиле темы где то добавили `<item name="android:background">...</item>`

Comment: @xkor я извиняюсь, а как тогда  правильно установить фон тулбару?

Comment: @xkor установил с помощью android:background="@color/colorPrimary" в лейауте. Просто раньше у меня этого сделать не получилось, поэтому посчитал данный вариант неправильным. Кстати, ваш комментарий помог, оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать атрибут `<item name="android:background">...</item>` в стилях темы. Он задаст не фон окна или корневой вьюхи как многие думают, а фон по умолчанию для всех вьюх. Соответственно этот фон будет использоваться для всех вьюх у которых не задан принудительно другой.

Собственно тема это есть набор атрибутов по умолчанию, так что вышеописанное относится не только к атрибуту фона.

Answer (score 1):

Где-то в гайдлайная ранее читал, что в экшенбаре все иконки получают прозрачность в 80%. При этом тексты тоже получают ее через апперанс. Однако, в toolbar текст титла не имеет такой возможности изначально.
Вам необходимо задать ааперанс самостоятельно следующим образом:
1. В стилях:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarTitleTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#90FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

где 90 - уровень прозрачности, который нужно подправить.
2. В разметке:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
   app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarTitleTextAppearance"
   app:layout_collapseMode="pin" 
/>
```

Comment: что то в styles.xml фреймворка [ничего такого](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L1251) для `ActionBar` нет. Устанавливается размер текста *Medium* и все. В любом случае прозрачность для атрибута TextColor повлияет на шрифт, а не на фон.